# How can I define more than one integer variable via for loop in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, variables, int

Imagine that we need 10 variables of integers to use but do not want to type them individually like `int a, b, c, d` and so on. I want to do it more effectively. Is there any way to make a for loop that defines all these variables?

I expect integers like `int a1, a2, a3, ..., a10;`.

Comment: I have had no luck finding a duplicate question to link to. This could be a good candidate for a canonical Q&A to connect the dots between "I want many similarly-named variables" and "Use an array". All the questions I've found assume one already knows that arrays exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a for loop, but you can use an *array*:

```
int a[10];
```

That will result in a single variable hosting 10 integers, accessible as `a[0]`, `a[1]`, ..., `a[9]`.